# ItextSharp implementation across load balancer

Tags: itext

We're evaluating ITextSharp (now known as IText) for producing pdf documents. This will be used in our websites which will be published across a load-balanced solution amongst several servers.

According to Itext, this will require a production license per server (we're not open-source) in our load balanced configuration, as well as uat and developer licenses. This is obviously a considerable investment.

Could anyone recommend any alternatives to reduce the costs?

Also, is there a pattern we could adopt to minimise the migration effort of the existing website prototype if we were to use another product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your architecture a bit and have a dedicated PDF generation server.  You'd then need to boil your requests down to something that could be sent between the servers.  Depending on your goals, that could be something relatively simple, such as a user ID and a report name, or complex (text layout, that image there).

As far as distancing yourself from the commercial iText, there are two options.

1) Use the older MPL iTextSharp.  It won't have all the latest features and bugfixes, but it's hard to beat the price.

2) The "wrapper" design pattern.  Build a relatively generic interface, and have your current implementation of that interface sit atop iText.  If you later need to swap it out, you're rebuilding the glue code, not your whole app.